# How to launch Calendar App programatically

Tags: android

I have a requirement where I need to launch Calendar App provided in mobile through on app on button click. Is there a way in which I can launch default calendar App in  Android?

Comment: Please explain, in programming terms, what "default calendar App in Android" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I think he means **that app** which consists in `a grid with day numbers and month names`...

Comment: Yes Exactly. Where we can create calendar events

Comment: Let me try boldface: please explain, **in programming terms**, what "default calendar App in Android" means. As a human, I know what a calendar app is. However, an Android device is not a human. Hence, you need to be able to explain, **in programming terms**, what you are seeking. For example, the one answer on this question is saying that, in programming terms, "default calendar App in Android" means "the `com.android.calendar` package". That's not a good answer, insofar as there is no requirement for any device to have that package, but at least it is expressed in programming terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this function on button click:

`public buttonPress(View view)
{
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(" com.android.calendar");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
}`

But you should try to avoid calling an application through an explicit intent. The reason for this is because a user may have multiple calendar applications on their device, you should be using a normal intent with a specific action relevant to what you're trying to use. Check the link below for this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html

Comment: This will actually not work on most devices since `com.android.calendar` is not even installed. Most manufacturers will replace the AOSP default with their own calendar app or the google apps one which is `com.google.android.calendar`